# C#: ZedGraph Show All Points of Zoomed Area

Tags: c#, list, zedgraph

I am plotting to my data to ZedGraph. Using `FileStream` to read files. Sometimes my data is greater than 200 megabyte. To draw this amount of data i should calculate peak values or must apply a window. However i want to see the all points of zoomed area. Please share any suggestion.

```
        PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
        int read;
        int count = 0;
        while (file.Position < file.Length)
        {
            read = file.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < read / window; i++)
            {
                list1.Add(count++, BitConverter.ToSingle(mainBuffer, i * window));
                count++;
            }
        }
        myCurve1 = zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[1].AddCurve(null, list1, Color.Lime, SymbolType.None);
        myCurve1.IsX2Axis = true;
        zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[1].XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
        zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[1].XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Invalidate();
```

`window=2048` for file size between 100 megabyte to 300 megabyte.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `PointPairList`, I would suggest to use a `FilteredPointList` instead. By this way, you can keep every points in memory, ZedGraph will only show the points that are necessary for display.

The `FilteredPointList` class is well explained [here](http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/indexe3e9.html?title=Use_a_FilteredPointList_to_reduce_the_number_of_points).

You will have to change your code a bit this way:

```
// Load the X, Y points in two double arrays
// ...

var list1 = new FilteredPointList(xArray, yArray);

// ...

// Use the ZoomEvent to adjust the bounds of the filtered point list

void zedGraphControl1_ZoomEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, ZoomState oldState, ZoomState newState)
{
    // The maximum number of point to displayed is based on the width of the graphpane, and the visible range of the X axis
    list1.SetBounds(sender.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min, sender.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max, (int)zgc.GraphPane.Rect.Width);

    // This refreshes the graph when the button is released after a panning operation
    if (newState.Type == ZoomState.StateType.Pan)
        sender.Invalidate();
}
```

**Edit**

If you can't not host all the points in memory, then you will have to provide your own `IPointList` implementation for ZedGraph using the logic in the code you describe above. You can inspire from the [FilteredPointList](https://github.com/discomurray/ZedGraph/blob/master/source/ZedGraph/FilteredPointList.cs) itself.

I would use the `SetBounds` method to preload the points from the disk, based on the decimation algorithm you already implemented, using the min, max and MaxPts in parameters.

Comment: To use FilteredPointList i need all of my data in array, don't i? If yes, i cant store whole data in array at one time because of out of memory exception.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try to customize it.