# c# winforms chart - scrolling large data issue

Tags: c#, winforms, plot, charts, large-data

I am using MS chart controls to visualize big amount of data - ECG signal with approx 1 million of points. But there is a scrollbar and the actual visible area is about 5 000 points, so the majority of them are hidden outside the chart area.

When I load 10-20k of points, it repaints fast enough when scrolling. But with 1 million of hidden points scrolling becomes very laggy.

How can I plot very long signal on the chart with scrollbar and small chart area, so that it can be fast opened and scrolled through the data? May be, there should be double buffering to increase repaint speed, or something like this?

UPD: So far I've resolved the issue going to ZedGraph library.
I've used `var line = new FilteredPointList(Double[], Double[]);` for my data array and method `line.SetBounds(Double, Double, Int32);`, called every time when 
`ScrollEvent` or `ZoomEvent` occur. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250775/c-zedgraph-show-all-points-of-zoomed-area).

But still don't know how to optimize MS chart. Wondering, if it has the same method to exclude excessive points from rendering.

Comment: If you don't mind using zedGraph why won't you just use it?

Comment: First, I have several simpler charts in my application.
Second, MS chart looks to be more "eye-candy".
Third, so far this chart is the only one to be problematic for MS chart.